# How to install libevent via aptitude?

Tags: linux, unix, installation, aptitude

It doesn't seem to work.

```
aptitude install libevent1
locate libevent

/usr/share/doc/libevent1
/usr/share/doc/libevent1/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libevent1/copyright
/var/cache/apt/archives/libevent1_1.3e-3_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libevent1.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libevent1.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libevent1.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libevent1.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libevent1.shlibs
falcon@cache1:~/src/beanstalkd-1.4.3$ libevent1
```

Comment: You might have better luck with dpkg -L libevent to see what the .deb actually installed. Voting to move this to superuser regardless.

Comment: What's your question?  If locate finds files of the package, then it is installed.  Did you mean libevent-dev?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just build it on your own?

http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent-1.4.13-stable.tar.gz

Download it, then run the usual

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
ldconfig
```

Comment: much better to use the system-provided package manager when possible.  installing it this way won't tell the package manager about it, so it won't handle dependent packages "correctly".

Answer (score 18):

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

Will do it.

Answer (score 0):

What distribution & version are you using?  According to [packages.debian.org](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/amd64/libevent1/filelist), that package should install the following files:

```
/usr/lib/libevent-1.1.so.1
/usr/lib/libevent-1.1a.so.1
/usr/lib/libevent-1.3b.so.1
/usr/lib/libevent-1.3d.so.1
/usr/lib/libevent-1.3e.so.1
/usr/lib/libevent-1.3e.so.1.0.3
/usr/lib/libevent.so.1
/usr/share/doc/libevent1/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libevent1/copyright
```